# How to vary gain value of gain block in Simulink during runtime

Tags: variable-assignment, simulink

The Gain block and continuous block in Simulink require the user to specify a gain. This can be a workspace variable. But I want to vary this gain during runtime. I can't seem to get a solution for this. This idea is simple but I can't believe it is so difficult to implement.

I have tried using another block to write to workspace, but found out that the 'to workspace' block only writes to the workspace after the simulation ends or pauses.

I can store the variable in a data memory block, but I don't know how to specify the gain value(s) for the gain/PID block in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Inline Parameters turned off (it's on the Optimization page of the Configuration Set), you can just open the gain block dialog and change the value.  If you want to use a workspace variable, then you can change the value of the workspace variable and do an Update Diagram (^D) while the simulation is running.

There's also a block called the [Slider Gain](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slidergain.html) which allows you to change the gain value using a slider UI.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that using the multiply block (instead of the gain block) connected to a data read block (this is the variable gain) as one of its inputs, is another alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

May be it'd be helpful at some point: try using the MATLAB Function Block (Matlab user-defined function that can be used directly in Simulink).

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. Thank you. I used a product block instead of gain and made one of the inputs to the product block to connect to the output of a MATLAB function. In the MATLAB function, I read the Simulink workspace variable and return it.

Answer (score 0):

As a command-line alternative, you can use the [SET_PARAM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) function to change the Gain value of the block during model simulation.

For example, the following code would change the Gain value of a block named "My Gain" at the top level of a model called "my_model.mdl" to a value of 20:

> ```
> set_param('my_model/My Gain','Gain','20');
> ```

Note, however, that only [Tunable Parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-tunable-parameters.html) can be changed with [SET_PARAM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) at runtime.